# Let $a \in F$, $v \in V$ and $av = 0$. Then, $a=0$ or $v=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I started working on "Linear algebra done right" exercises and I have run into a super easy problem that I will never come by my own.

Problem:
Suppose $a \in F$, $v \in V$, and $av=0$. Prove that $a=0$ or $v=0$

Solution:

[image]

My question:
Is this the only way this problem can be solved?

Comment: To be clear: Is $F$ a field, and is $V$ a vector space? (Be sure to include such details in the body of the question.)

Comment: Short answer: yes.